# Extract values from configuration file with regex

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a configuration file and extract some parameters, these are:

- Hostname
- Status (active)

They follow a standard XML format, where the primary key (hostame) is inside `<hostname>` and below the values ​​that end with `<hostname/>`
My regex seems to work like the example below, however when I read `dataCfg` don't receive any value.

The print row I put in the code just to see if something is being returned, but the output I want is the commented print lines `#`

#### filter.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf8
import re

# Strings regex
regexCfg = r"<(.*)>\n      active = (.*)"

# Get file .cfg
with open("/etc/ansible/files/net_connect.cfg", 'r') as cfgfile:
    dataCfg = cfgfile.readlines()

# Capture values
# Realize regex in string
filterdCfg = re.findall(regexCfg, str(dataCfg), re.MULTILINE)

# Print regex value
print("[RESULT] Row: {}".format(filterdCfg))
#print("Hostname: {}".format(filterdCfg[0][0]))
#print("Status: {}".format(filterdCfg[0][1]))
```

#### Output

```
[RESULT] Row: []
```

#### Desired Output

```
Hostname: SERVENFE
Status: yes
Hostname: SERVENFE2
Status: yes
```

#### Data file

```xml
   <SERVENFE>
      active = yes
   <SERVENFE>
   <SERVENFE2>
      active = yes
   <SERVENFE2>
```

[Regex example](https://regex101.com/r/T7cXfw/1)

Comment: If you are allowed to use something other than regex, I recommend using a library (such as xmltodict: https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) instead.

Comment: Should I install with this pip? https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/

Comment: Yes. you can use the command: pip install xmltodict

Comment: I didn't know this lib, I'll do some tests, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @YahiaZakaria I tested it, but the file is not valid XML

Comment: xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 5359, column 4

Comment: That makes sense. I just noticed that the example you have is not valid according to XML standards. First, the closing tag of each element should have a backslash, so it should look like: <SERVENFE>active = yes</SERVENFE><SERVENFE2>active = yes</SERVENFE2>. Also, you can only have one parent element, while the example have 2 elements at the upper level so they must be enclosed within another element.
An example of a valid xml: <PARENT><SERVENFE> active = yes </SERVENFE><SERVENFE2> active = yes </SERVENFE2></PARENT>

Comment: If you can change the format, then try to change it such that it follows the XML standards. If not, then you will need custom code to parse it since any XML parser will probably fail.

Comment: Okay, I'll see what is possible to do, because this .cfg file is created by the software, I'm just using it, but thanks for the tips !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `.readlines()`. That reads the file into a list of lines. Simply use `.read()` instead, to read it into one big string. I.e.

```
dataCfg = cfgfile.read()
```

Output:

```
[RESULT] Row: [('SERVENFE', 'yes'), ('SERVENFE2', 'yes')]
```

However, as mentioned in the comments, parsing is ultimately the better way, though your example is not valid XML.